# i want to change the animation play state to running using javascript or jquery on click. any help is appriciated

Tags: html

i want to change the animation play state to running from javascript or jquery on click. any help is appreciated.

    Running Word
    
    play
    
    
    body {
     background: #666;
     }
     p {
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 2em;
     }

```
.word {
 position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: lightblue;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,1); 
 }

 .word::after {   // i have doubt here
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40%;
  animation: run-text 5s infinite linear;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,255,1); 
    animation-play-state: ;
   }

  @keyframes run-text {
  from { width: 0 }
   to { width: 100% }
 }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You separate the animation class and add it with jQuery.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('run-text');
});
```

```css
.word {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .word::after {
  display: none;
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
  color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,255,1); 
 }
 .run-text:after {
   display: block;
   animation: run-text 1s forwards linear;
 }
 @keyframes run-text {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="word" data-text="Other Text">Some Text</a>
```

Comment: thank you sir. can i time the animation to  the timing of a video ? if yes please help

Comment: Please submit a new question and test case for any additional questions you may have and accept this as the answer if it has answered your question.